# how to create docker container using jenkins pipeline script

Tags: docker, containers

node{
    stage('Scm Checkout'){
        git credentialsId: 'git-creds', url: 'https://github.com/mouthik/jenkinsfile.git'
    }
    stage('Build docker image'){
      sh 'docker build -t mouthik/my-app:2.0.0 .'

```
stage('Run docker container'){
  sh 'docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -name my-app mouthik/my-app:2.0.0'
 }

}
```

}

Comment: I tried these code but i'm getting error message as /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-test@tmp/durable-89bb0168/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-test@tmp/durable-89bb0168/script.sh: docker: not found

Comment: Please tell me solution how to create container using jenkins pipeline

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Please gather all elements in your question instead of spraying it across comments, it will dramatically improve readability. Note that you always can edit your own question. Give a chance to [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to install docker on the slave.

Try

```
sudo dnf install docker-ce
```

and start the docker service
to build a docker image you need to write [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

and then docker build https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: you mean to say, i have to create slave job and install docker on that job using dockerfile , then i can create a docker container?

Comment: thn what will be there in jenkins master

Comment: You mean to say, i need to create a slave job and then using pipeline script i can create docker image and container ? is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly, you can install docker on master node also then create a Dockerfile with your requirements then build and run.

Comment: I'm running everything in master where docker is installed, but still getting the same error, is there anyway to run this job in the master itself?

Comment: Please help me with this

Comment: i'm writing the script in jenkins pipeline, if you have any code can just provide me for reference